# .htaccess, rewrite a dictionary to a subfolder inside

Tags: .htaccess

I've attempted this many times using questions before, heres a method I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /~admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dist/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dist/$1 [L]
```

But that doesn't seem to work, here is what I'm trying to achieve: *www.example.com/admin/dist/* contains the administration panel, I wish to reroute that to *www.example.com/admin/* but can still access the folder *www.example.com/admin/src/*

I am also using WAMPServer on Windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this in your `admin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dist/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dist/$1 [L]
```